# Printing Product Variant HS Codes

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to create an automated Commercial Invoice within Shopify, using the Liquid template language.  I have everything working, except for the IMPORT/EXPORT Harmonized Codes (HS Tariff Codes) that are stored as variant meta-fields.  Whenever I try to print them out using the following code, I get blanks:

`{% for line_item in line_items %}
   {{ line_item.variant.metafields.global_harmonized_system_code }}
 {% endfor %}`

Can someone help me pull these HS Codes for each product variant and print them on the Commercial Invoice using liquid to pull the meta-field?

Comment: Are you sure the data you are pulling is actually present in your platform?
What do you see if you just use `{% line_items %}` ?

Comment: The problem I am having is figuring out the name of the metafield, and then how to directly access it.  I know the value is present in the system, and the URL to access this specific metafield in bulk is:  /admin/bulk?resource_name=Product&order=title+asc&edit=variants.metafields_global_harmonized_system_code

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the problem is with the logic or with the data you're dealing with.  What do you see if you just use `{% line_items %}`?
If it returns nothing, you are running an if statement on an empty object.

Comment: Isn't the `global_harmonized_system_code` the namespace? Where is your metafield key?

Comment: Adriano, when I try to add {% line_items %} to my template, I get an error. {% line_items.title %} works fine though.

Comment: drip, I'm not sure how to figure that out....that's why I am asking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Global is a namespace, try :

```
{{ line_item.variant.metafields.global.harmonized_system_code }}
```

The syntax is :

```
{{ your_object.metafields.namespace.key }}
```

Comment: OK, so I tried {{ line_item.variant.metafields.global_harmonized_system_code }} and I got a blank.  I did verify that the line_items do have the HS CODE configured for each variant, and it is TRUE.

Comment: but you have to try with
{{ line_item.variant.metafields.global.harmonized_system_code }} (a dot after global)

Comment: Sorry. I did try it exactly as you typed...I just copied the wrong test line back into the response to you.  I just verified again, that {{ line_item.variant.metafields.global.harmonized_system_code }} isn;t working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Liquid is insufficient for the task at hand.

```
 {{ line_item.variant.metafields.global_harmonized_system_code }}
```

That output is not valid. It might point to a set of one or more key value pairs, so you should really iterate on that. Example:

```
{% for mf in line_item.variant.metafields.global %}
  {% if mf | first == 'harmonized_system_code' %}
     <p> {{ mf | last }} how is that for some value! </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Something like that is more precise and will go through the variant metafields allowning you to choose which ones to print out.

Comment: This didn't print anything out.  Not sure why.

Comment: Make sure your metafields exist. Easy to audit, just install Chrome browser with plugin ShopifyFD, and you can see your metafields. Then and only then, if they are correct would your loops to output their info work.

Comment: Hi David.  I have ShopifyFD installed, and I can verify that the meta-tag (exactly typed) is "global.harmonized_system_code", and it contains a value "570650"

Comment: Here is your new code then...

{% for mf in line_item.variant.metafields.global %}
  {% if mf | first == ''harmonized_system_code" %}
     <p> {{ mf | last }} how is that for some value! </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: global is your namespace,

harmonized_system_code is your key and it has a value...

Comment: Yea, that didn't work either.  Just printing blanks.  It's like it can't directly access the metafield variable for some reason.

Comment: Sorry... code works fine for me. Guess you're close but no cigar in your attempts!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the value using this

```
{{ line_item.variant.metafields.harmonized_system_code.value }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for line_item in line_items %}
{{ line_item.variant.metafields.harmonized_system_code.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will show the HS code