# Shopify - Display a product HS code within a packing slip

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to display a HS code in an order packing slip in Shopify. This older post [Printing Product Variant HS Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991557/printing-product-variant-hs-codes) is no longer applicable as this is contained within the InventoryItem now rather than as a metafield: https://shopify.dev/changelog/the-inventoryitem-resource-now-includes-hs-codes-country-codes-and-province-codes

Answer (score 0):

its currently not possible to add it to the native shopify solution, we have added HS code and Country of origin to our Order Related Documents app:

https://apps.shopify.com/order-related-documents

you can use the packing slip template and update it with the drag and drop editor.

[image: Order Related Documents]